# Configset directory missing when using host-mounted directories

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

Using latest Docker image for Solr. I have created configsets using dockerfile copying my configset files to /var/solr/data/configsets/

When I start it using named volume the, configsets works fine.

But when I do it using host-mounted directories on windows, the configsets are missing and I don't find configset folder at this location
/var/solr/data/

Check https://prnt.sc/ts6dme

This gives me following error:

"Error CREATEing SolrCore 'my_core': Unable to create core [my_core] Caused by: Could not load configuration from directory /var/solr/data/configsets/my_core_config"

Here is the dockerfile

> FROM solr:8 USER root
>
> RUN mkdir /myconfigset && chown -R solr:solr /myconfigset
>
> COPY --chown=solr:solr ./myconfigset /myconfigset/ WORKDIR
> /var/solr/data/configsets/ RUN mkdir /myconfigset_core_config && chown
> -R solr:solr /myconfigset_core_config
>
> COPY --chown=solr:solr ./myconfigset/myconfigset_core_config
> /var/solr/data/configsets/myconfigset_core_config/
>
> COPY --chown=solr:solr /myconfigset/sqljdbc822.jar
> /opt/solr/contrib/dataimporthandler-extras/lib/ USER solr
>
> RUN chmod -R a+X /myconfigset
>
> WORKDIR /opt/solr

Comment: You should probably include your docker configuration - that's what would be relevant. If the directories are not available inside your container, there's little Solr can do about it.

Comment: @MatsLindh Added dockerfile into the question.